# Import iCal data from other mac

Tags: ical, migration

I need to consolidate two iCal installations: the data from my old laptop should be merged into my new laptop’s iCal data.

I tried exporting the old iCal data and importing it on the new laptop. Unfortunately, this would *replace* all my new iCal data. I don’t want this. I also don’t want to export/import separate calendars – I want to *merge* them (i.e. “work” with “work”, and “home” with “home”).

Is there a (hopefully painless) way of achieving this?

<sub><sup>Note to self: use cloud-based calendar in future</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.macworld.com/article/54668/2007/01/mergecalendars.html

This seems to be doing exactly what you ask.