# Merging two calendars in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, calendar, ical

I need to merge two calendars in macOS Sierra Calendar App. I found [instructions](http://www.macworld.com/article/1054668/software/mergecalendars.html) on the web that describe how to do this with previous versions of OS X, however these are not relevant for macOS Sierra. The answer to this question provides the [same steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39901/18285), which does not solve my problem.

Basically, the problem is if you export the calendar, then import the calendar, it will simply import back into the original calendar, giving you no choice to where you want it imported. There is never an option to select a target calendar as described in the previously mentioned steps.

Is it no longer possible to merge two calendars in macOS Sierra Calendar App? Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's an even easier way with Sierra. Toggle the Calendar Sidebar if not already showing. From the Sidebar, select the Calendar you wish to merge into another. Select "Merge Calendar" from under the edit menu. Select the calendar you want to merge the Sidebar selected calendar into.

One additional note: If the calendar is "Shared," then merge is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I just performed the following experiment:

1. created a new calendar, Test, and created one event.
2. selected Test and selected File > Export > Export… and saved Test.ics the Desktop.
3. Deleted the Test calendar
4. From the desktop, dragged and dropped Test.ics to my *existing* Personal calendar.

The event was imported into that calendar. It did not recreate the Test calendar.

Note I did *not* choose File > Import…

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish. Try it and see?

I also tried another variation: I clicked File > Import… and selected the file on the desktop. Calendar asked me which Calendar to use when importing my event. I chose the one I wanted and it performed as desired.

Comment: i'm using sierra, but i did this on several versions for myself and for clients. This is a feature that's been around for dog's ears and hasn't changed much. I'm sure I've used it on 10.11, 10.10, and maybe even 10.9

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying this and discovered that it's now even easier (maybe it's been updated in the last few months?). I made a test calendar with an event, exported it, went to delete the test calendar (Edit > Delete) and it asked me if I wanted to merge it or delete it. If you say merge it just brings up the list of your other calendars so you can choose which to merge it with.